# no such file to load -- action_controller/integration - NoMethodError for Rails 3 and Webrat

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, webrat

I'm getting the following failure during RSpec tests..

`no such file to load -- action_controller/integration`

..using Rails 3, RSpec 2 and Webrat, if I include the Webrat helpers in the following way (the idea was to use Webrat for the `have_tag` and `have_selector` methods instead of `assert_select`).

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ..
  config.include Webrat::HaveTagMatcher
end
```

Yet apparently [Webrat and Rails 3 are not compatible](http://railsplugins.org/plugins/26-webrat) yet. One solution is to avoid the Webrat gem and to use `assert_select` instead. Has anyone a better solution? How do you avoid the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found a solution for this problem, only a work around. You can use the `have_selector` method of Capybara instead of Webrat, at least in RSpec request tests. There are certain difficulties with [RSpec2 and Capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260720/rspec2-and-capybara) (`page.should have_selector` only works if you use Capybara's 'visit' method, and not the RSpec method get '/some/path'), but basically it works.