# RSpec2 and Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, capybara

Capybara is confusing me. If I use Capybara in combination with Ruby on Rails 3 and RSpec 2, then in RSpec request tests, the following matcher works:

```
response.body.should have_selector "div.some_class"
```

The response object has the class `ActionDispatch::TestResponse`. But the following line, which [should work officially](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara), does not work:

```
page.should have_selector "div.some_class"
```

The page object has the class `Capybara::Session`. In which cases do you have to use the `response.body` object and when do you have to use a `page` object ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So I just ran into similar, and this is I think what's going on:

It depends on code you didn't include here of how you visit the page. I'm writing an rspec request spec.

If I retrieve the page with rspec's own:

```
get '/some/path'
```

then response.body.should have_selector works as you say, but page.should does not.

To make Capybara 'page' work (and to make Capybara interactions like click_button or fill_in work), instead of retrieving with rspec's 'get', you need to retrieve with Capybara's 'visit':

```
visit '/some/path'
page.should have_selector("works")
```

'page', a capybara method,  only gets set when using 'visit', a capybara method.

This does get confusing, all the mixing and matching of different libraries involved in rails testing.

Comment: Execellent answer. That is the difference. If you use rspec's get "/some/path", then response.body contains the resulting page and you can use response.body.should have_selector. If you Capybara's visit "/some/path", then page.body contains the resulting page and you can use page.should have_selector.

Comment: the above fix didn't work for me - I still get the same error with visit ... and you are right it is damn confusing :-)

Answer (score 3):

You would use `response` when you want to use the standard rails methods. And, alternately, you'd use `page` when you want to use the capybara methods. In capybara you'd most likely use `have_css` in the example given.

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't realize that capybara has a have_selector method. But the answer remains, `page` for capybara, `response` for rails.

Comment: but why does "page.should have something" does not work? we use require "capybara/rspec" and require "capybara/rails" in our Rails 3 app, and yet "page.should .." does not work in RSpec request tests.

Comment: I wish I knew. Seems that mixing the RSpec and Capybara syntaxes causes some problem. I know that `page.body has_content?` works for me where `page.should have_content` rarely does.

Comment: I've begun to just use `page.should have_xpath` everywhere.