# Writing rspec test to check form path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, integration-testing

How can I write a test to check the path on a form?

I'm trying this:

```
it "has a proper form path given subdomains" do    
  @event = Factory :event
  get events_path(@event), nil,  {'HTTP_HOST' => 'staging.example.com' }
  page.should have_selector "form", :action => "secure.staging.example.com"
end
```

But it doesn't look like my test is working:

```
 Failure/Error: page.should have_selector "form", :action => "secure.staging.example.com"
   expected css "form" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/events_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned a lot about testing in solving this like the difference between [page and response variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260720/rspec2-and-capybara).

What I really needed to do was write [a helper spec](http://pastie.org/3561232) to test that my url_for helper method was prepending subdomains properly.  But I also figured out the view spec code:

```
it "has a proper form path given subdomains" do    
  assign :event, Factory(:event)

  controller.request.host = "staging.example.com"

  render

  assert_select "form[action*=?]", "secure.staging.example.com"
end
```