# how to match css class and text in capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, bdd

I have the following integration step to check for a `.credits_count` class and a `0 credits on it`.

```
it "show credits available at the top." do 
  user = Factory.create(:user)
  login_as(user, :scope => :user)
  page.should have_selector('.credits_count', text: '0 credits')
end
```

The problem is that I'm getting the following errors when the `.credits_count` is on the page with its text.

```
  Credits when user is non-enabled show user credits available at the top.
   Failure/Error: page.should have_selector('.credits_count', text: '0 credits')
   expected css ".credits_count" with text "0 credits" to return something
   # ./spec/requests/credits_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Any idea why its not seeing the `.credits_count` selector?

The view layout looks like this.

```
# app/views/layouts/application.html.haml
- if current_user
  %li.credits_count
    = current_user.credits_count
    credits
```

Comment: You created the credits_count as a id for li tag in you view file, but you are looking for credits_count as a class. I think it may the problem.

Comment: Good point, but I'm afraid it still happens even fixing that (giving same error).

Comment: It might have to do with the fact that "0 credits" is split across two lines. What if you take out the `text: '0 credits'` part of the arguments to `have_selector`? If that passes then you know that the text is the problem.

Comment: can you try this. should have_selector("li", :class => "credits_count", :content => "0 credits")

Answer (score 0):

To make Capybara 'page' work you need to retrieve the page with Capybara's 'visit', see [this question about RSpec and Capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260720/rspec2-and-capybara).