# Can't get save_and_open_page to work in rspec for typo project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

So I'm working on the EdX part 2 homework 1, and I cannot seem to get save_and_open_page working.

Here's the rspec chunk:

```
    describe 'merge action' do

  before do
    @article_for_merging = Factory(:article)
    @article_for_merging.body = 'something we will merge'
  end

  it 'should merge articles' do
    get :merge, 'id' => @article.id, 'merge_with' =>  @article_for_merging.id
    response.should render_template('new')
    assigns(:article).should_not be_nil
    assigns(:article).should be_valid
    response.should contain(/body/)
    response.should contain(/extended content/)
    save_and_open_page
    debugger
    response.should have_field('article[body]',:with => @article.body + @article_for_merging.body)
    response.should have_selector('form#merge input#merge_with')
    response.should have_selector('form#merge input#merge')
  end
end
```

Other stack overflow posts suggest solutions:

[RSpec2 and Capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260720/rspec2-and-capybara)

http://paikialog.wordpress.com/2012/02/11/webrat-no-such-file-to-load-action_controllerintegration/

[save_and_open_page (capybara / launchy) stopped working in a project - error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608976/save-and-open-page-capybara-launchy-stopped-working-in-a-project-error)

and I believe I have tried all, but I cannot get it to work.  It's frustrating because I can view the raw HTML but with big pages it's such a pain to ferret out the html details I need - looking in browser with things like chrome's "inspect element" is SO much easier.

Whatever combination of suggested solutions I've tried I keep coming back to some variation on this error:

1) Admin::ContentController with admin connection merge action should merge articles
     Failure/Error: save_and_open_page
     LoadError:
       no such file to load -- action_controller/integration
     # ./spec/controllers/admin/content_controller_spec.rb:498:in `block (4 levels) in '

Any help very much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

ah, I think this might have fixed it:

http://paikialog.wordpress.com/2012/02/11/webrat-no-such-file-to-load-action_controllerintegration/

Comment: hmm, seems I have to use 'visit' rather than get, but then that doesn't play well with the rest of the specs from typo

Comment: oh well I hacked my own solution: File.open('/tmp/test.html','w'){|file| file.write(response.body)}
`firefox '/tmp/test.html'`

Answer (score 1):

Working from [Sam Joseph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/316729/sam-joseph)'s hacked solution in the comments, I wrote this method and put it in spec/support/helpers.rb:

```
def save_and_open_rspec_page
  File.open('/tmp/test.html','w'){|file| file.write(rendered)}; `open '/tmp/test.html'`
end
```

`response.body` didn't work for me, presumably because I'm in a view spec?

`firefox` didn't work for me either. Since I'm on a Mac, I used `open` instead.

Also, I called `render` before `save_and_open_rspec_page` on my view spec.